# CONTAINSTABLE does not respond

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When trying to search for a text like "1.2.3.4" using the `CONTAINSTABLE` function, there seems to be no response and it keeps on loading and sql memory gets full.

The query I have used is

```
SELECT * 
  FROM CONTAINSTABLE(document_text, [text], '"1.2.3.4*"')
```

Comment: can you add a few rows of your table?

Comment: [same question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b36a65fa-5161-4955-8d49-ebdff4f801c6/containstable-does-not-respond?forum=transactsql), same lack of detail